Prisma setup issue
While install prisma from last 2 days. I'm not able to figure out the issue
npm init -y
npm install prisma typescript tsx @types/node --save-dev
npx tsc --init
npx prisma
output :
`◭  Prisma is a modern DB toolkit to query, migrate and model your database (https://prisma.io)
Usage

  $ prisma [command]

Commands

            init   Set up Prisma for your app
        generate   Generate artifacts (e.g. Prisma Client)
              db   Manage your database schema and lifecycle
         migrate   Migrate your database
          studio   Browse your data with Prisma Studio
        validate   Validate your Prisma schema
          format   Format your Prisma schema
         version   Displays Prisma version info
           debug   Displays Prisma debug info

Flags

     --preview-feature   Run Preview Prisma commands
     --help, -h          Show additional information about a command

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│  Optimize performance through connection pooling and caching with Prisma Accelerate  │
│  and capture real-time events from your database with Prisma Pulse.                  │
│  Learn more at https://pris.ly/cli/pdp                                               │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Examples

  Set up a new Prisma project
  $ prisma init

  Generate artifacts (e.g. Prisma Client)
  $ prisma generate

  Browse your data
  $ prisma studio

  Create migrations from your Prisma schema, apply them to the database, generate artifacts (e.g. Prisma Client)
  $ prisma migrate dev

  Pull the schema from an existing database, updating the Prisma schema
  $ prisma db pull

  Push the Prisma schema state to the database
  $ prisma db push

  Validate your Prisma schema
  $ prisma validate

  Format your Prisma schema
  $ prisma format

  Display Prisma version info
  $ prisma version

  Display Prisma debug info
  $ prisma debug`

npx prisma init
gives this error Error: (0 , CSe.isError) is not a function
Cannot figure it out these are my node and ts version respectively , v23.3.0 ,Version 5.6.3
I want to install prisma and this gives error gives
: Error: (0 , CSe.isError) is not a function

It seems that the issue is related to Node.js v23, which is causing incompatibilities with Prisma.
While searching for a solution to this error, I came across this discussion: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/25463
Downgrading to a supported Node.js version (such as v20, v18, or v16) should resolve the issue.
take a look at this one too: https://nodejs.org/en/about/previous-releases
